# Scaling down Raspbian for Adafruit PiTFT 1.14"

Tags: raspbian, gpio, display, raspberry-pi-desktop, adafruit

I want to use the Adafruit PiTFT ([click here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-mini-pitft-135x240-color-tft-add-on-for-raspberry-pi/kernel-module-install)) 1.14" with the Raspbian Desktop. How can I scale the Raspbian Desktop down so that it will be normally sized on the 240x135 px screen? An example with some different screens might look like [this](https://www.hackster.io/Tylersuard/raspberry-pi-smart-watch-a0243b) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQOcx_JoAWE).

PS: I already tried "framebufferwidth" and "framebufferheight"

Answer (score 1):

You can change pretty much everything desktop-related with this command:

```
lxappearance
```

That will let you change font sizes for GTK GUIs, as well as the font size for the title bar (window border), as well as icon theme, gtk theme, mouse cursor, window border color, etc.

Then to shrink the taskbar/panel, right-click --> Panel Settings --> Height --> set to something like 20.
You can also make the panel minimize when not in use via the Advanced tab.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that and get to you if it works.

Comment: Error: Cannot open display:
What does this mean?

Comment: Assuming you get that error when you run `lxappearance`, are you running that from a gui terminal inside the desktop session?

Comment: No. Ill use VNC then.

Comment: I thought you said you needed to scale down the **desktop session**. Do you need to edit your question?

Comment: No
, I was using ssh since my screen is too tiny.

Comment: Oh I see. I think you need to run lxappearance inside the desktop session. Maybe this will work from your ssh: `DISPLAY=:0 lxappearance`

Comment: Or you can use VNC :)  But make sure you've enabled it in `raspi-config` so it runs in **service mode**, not virtual mode.

Comment: I did lxappearance fine, but when I open Chromium, all you can see is a tiny part of the screen, like this: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1xLLu6avJFfIahXfErfrgRu9qdiy1XkubH-K82TpLJ5E/edit?usp=sharing How do I fix this? @Botspot

Comment: Chromium ignores nearly all configuration of GTK, openbox, etc. Try this: `chromium-browser --device-scale-factor=0.5`